# Linq : check for null value before accessing the property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Please advice regarding the error.
This is the code

```
   void Main()
   {
      var a = from id in TechnicalProducts
        where id.Id == "ID-4591"
        select new {
         Country = id.Computers.Select (x => new {x.Location.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.Code}),
        };
      Console.WriteLine(a);
   }
```

Error: An entry returned by the navigation property 'Code' is null and cannot be initialized. You should check for a null value before accessing this property

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
somevar = x.Location.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.Code ?? 0
```

**EDIT :**
    your code may look something like this:

```
var a = from id in TechnicalProducts
        where id.Id == "ID-4591"
        select new {
         Country = id.Computers.Select (
              x => new{
                x.Location.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.Code ?? 0
                      }
        )};
```

Comment: but where would i add this line?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a null check in your query:

```
WHERE x.Location.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.Code != null
```

Otherwise use the [coalesce operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) as @Behnam has suggested.  This operator just returns the first non-null value in the chain.

Comment: as an additional condition in your where statement

Comment: so the stmt looks like this. right? where id.Id == "ID-14591" && x.Location.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.ParentLocation.Code != null But then it gives a new error. "The name 'x' does not exist in the current context"